# NullReferenceException error C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
        QueryClass Query;
        string UserName = "";
        int UserId = 0;


        string email = txtEmail.Text;
        string name = txtUserName.Text;
        string phone = txtPhone.Text;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

            UserName = Query.GetUserName(email); //returns a string value

            if (UserName != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(UserName + " is already in the database");
            }

            if (Query.AddNewUser(name, email, phone) == true) //returns a bool value
            {
                UserId = Query.GetUserId(email); //returns a int value
                if (Query.AddNewImage(UserId, buffer) == true) //returns a bool value
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Done..!!");
                }

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Error");
```

I'm getting the following error after I click the insert button (above code) of my program.

```
System.NullReferenceException
Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

I'm getting that exception on following places. (i didn't check other places) code just stops these places and gives the error.

```
UserName = Query.GetUserName(email); //returns a string value

if (Query.AddNewUser(name, email, phone) == true) //returns a bool value
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this error? I'm using Visual studio 2010.

Comment: Please choose a better title and format your question a little bit better. See also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Also please not comments were not invented to be used to state the obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using `Query` without actually setting it to anything.  You likely need to construct an instance:

```
// Change: QueryClass Query;
QueryClass Query = new QueryClass();
```

Without creating an instance, when you call:

```
 UserName = Query.GetUserName(email);
```

At this point, `Query` is still the default value (which is `null` for a reference type), and you'll get a `NullReferenceException` upon trying to use it.

On a side note, you might want to consider naming this variable `query` (lower case), and the class `Query` (or, better yet, a more descriptive name), in order to follow the normal .NET naming guidelines.

Comment: Oh I've made a mistake there. thank you sir. you saved my day..